# Can BFS reach the goal if the depth is infinite?

Tags: search, graph, branch, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I have one scenario: what happen if the branch is only one and the goal node is at infinite depth? Can I actually assume that the goal node at infinite depth?

Comment: DFS is a distributed filesystem from Microsoft. Note: for questions about depth-first search, please use the depth-first-search tag. **NOT to be confused** with [depth-first-search]

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear to me. You may want to [edit], add more information and clarify.

Comment: So I found that BFS is incomplete if the branching factor is infinite but complete in graph with infinite depth, while DFS is incomplete if the depth is infinite but complete if branching factor is infinite. Now, I want to try to argue that BFS is incomplete even if the depth is infinite. Just set the goal node at infinite depth and hence BFS is incomplete? @c0der